# RSA public key to base 64

Tags: c#, rsa

I have generated and RSA public key :

```
 RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(4096);

 var pub_key = rsaProvider.ExportParameters(false); // export public key
 var priv_key = rsaProvider.ExportParameters(true); // export private key
```

I need a way to decode pub_key it into `base64` so I can send it, any suggestions

Answer (score 3):

When you say Base64 do you mean that you need the public key in Base64 PEM format?  If so, consider using BouncyCastle.

```
var kp = [Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities].GetKeyPair(rsaProvider);
using (var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
{
    var pw = new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemWrite(sw);
    pw.WriteObject(kp.Public);
    var pem  = sw.ToString();
    return pem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear exactly what you need but I'm guessing you are looking to serialize the key. In that case you can use the [`RSA.ToXmlString() method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.toxmlstring.aspx). If you really need to base64 encode it then you the method in Nickolay Olshevsky's answer to further encode the XML string.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET there is a builtin function to convert to Base64 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx

Comment: i know how to use this. thank you for your answer but i need a specific resolution for the RSA public key, as in rsa key there is many keys, what is the order or which one i should use